# How to pass parameter from the .js file of D3 to .js file of Arcgis Api by JavaScript?

Tags: d3.js, arcgis-js-api

I use the D3 and ArcGIS API 3.19 to develop an interactive Web.In the`.js` file of ArcGis API, I use the following code to build an URL to get a `.json`.

```
    var timeinterval =geo;
    var locationURL="https://paleobiodb.org/data1.2/colls/list.json?lngmin=-125&lngmax=-60&latmin=25&latmax=50&limit=all&show=time&level=3";
    locationURL += "&"+"interval="+timeinterval;
```

In the `.js` file of D3, I ues *double click* to get the `d.name`.

```
var g=svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(partition.nodes(root))
         .enter().append("svg:g")
        .on("click", clicked)
        .on("dblclick",TransInterval);
```

In the `function TransInterval`, the first `console.log()`can get a output.but the second gets nothing.

```
var geo;//the global variable
function TransInterval(d){
   var wa= d.name;
   geo=wa;
   console.log(geo);
   return geo;
    };
   console.log(geo);
```

So,I want to know how to pass the `d.name` to a global variable,and can be use in `.js`file of the ArcGis API? Thank You!

Comment: Which do you consider to be first `console.log()`, inside the function or outside?

Comment: `console.log()`Inside the function is the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any problem with the way you have written the code. The value from `d.name` will be assigned to variable `geo` when the function `TransInterval` is called.

What you need to understand about JavaScript is, the variable are function scoped. So at the time the second `console.log(geo)` is executed, the function `TransInterval` might not have been called.

Comment: I check the execution order by `console.log(1)`   and  `console.log(2)` . the outside is executed firstly. Thank you for an answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Accept the answer, so that it would help others.